# How do I check and change turtle coordinates efficiently in Python?

Tags: python, function, syntax-error, coordinates, turtle-graphics

I am quite new to Python and I have started a Sokoban game. I have been testing this code for checking coords to ensure the box/player moves back when walking into a wall. I tried making a little loop and the function, but I keep getting errors.

```
import turtle
wn=turtle.Screen()
a=turtle.Turtle()
b=turtle.Turtle()


def checking(x,y):
    if x.xcor()==y.xcor() and x.ycor()==y.ycor():
        return True
    else:
        return False


if checking(a,b)==True:
    a.xcor()=a.xcor()+50
```

Syntax error- Cannot assign to function call 
The a in the last line is highlighted.

The checking function works as this code worked perfectly.

```
import turtle
wn=turtle.Screen()
a=turtle.Turtle()
b=turtle.Turtle()


def checking(x,y):
    if x.xcor()==y.xcor() and x.ycor()==y.ycor():
        return True
    else:
        return False


if checking(a,b)==True:
    wn.bgcolor("blue")
```

I would appreciate if anyone knew a way to fix the code. Thank you!

Comment: It's true that you can't set a value to a function. Turtle has a `setx()` function that you can use to set the x coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

This line is a problem:

```
a.xcor()=a.xcor()+50
```

as `xcor()` is used to access a coordinate, not set one.  You want `setx()`:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

wn = Screen()

a = Turtle()
b = Turtle()

def checking(x, y):
    return x.xcor() == y.xcor() and x.ycor() == y.ycor()
    # or better yet: return x.position() == y.position()

if checking(a, b):
    a.setx(a.xcor() + 50)
```

Here's your next issue -- the `checking()` function won't work in the long term.  Turtles crawl a floating point plane and they often don't return to the exact position they left, e.g. `(0, 0)` vs `(0, 0.001)`.  To deal with this, we'll need a less exact comparison:

```
def checking(a, b):
    return abs(a.xcor() - b.xcor()) < 1 > abs(a.ycor() - b.ycor())
```

or better yet:

```
def checking(a, b):
    return a.distance(b) < 1
```